# Dell Laptop and Generic Bluetooth Radio

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, bluetooth

I have a Cambridge Silicon Wave Link Bluetooth Adapter and need info, the driver version is 5.1 260.5512 distributed by Microsoft. How do I tell if a Bluetooth receiver will accept a signal to it from this dongle? I want a 2.1
receiver with edr capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

Although your question isn't clear, I think this will likely answer your question...

That BT adapter has been discontinued for a very long time, and the proprietary drivers haven't been offered for 7+ years so you must use the Microsoft BT stack. The Microsoft BT stack that is used by Windows XP only supports Bluetooth 1.1, 2.0, and 2.0 and EDR, and not 2.1 according to [Microsoft's General Bluetooth support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn133849(v=vs.85).aspx) page.

Also, although I cannot verify it specifically by searching, the age of that adapter suggests it only supports Bluetooth 1.0 or 2.0 even with it's proprietary drivers (assuming you can find them).

In order to get Bluetooth 2.1 with EDR support, you must have at least Windows Vista and a compatible adapter.

Some devices do support backwards compatibility, but since you didn't state what device you are trying/wanting to connect, I can't answer that question.